# Convert dynamic REF TO DATA structure to static

Tags: dynamic, abap

I created structure with three components, one of which is type ref to data and a table type of this structure. The problem is, how do I add data to this table?

It always has three components, but only one of them is discovered during processing, I always know two of them. Thus I always use the entire table type `ref to data` and then determine the type of this structure and create the table on it.

The issue here is that by doing this, even though I know two of the components, the whole itab will be dynamic, so I must use it in methods exporting/importing a type ref to data, which is inconvenient.

The method below will always return a table type ref to data, which is completely dynamic (type ref to data), but the structure of the table will always be like this:

- component 1 -> type pc261.
- component 2 -> type pay99_international.
- compoment 3 -> well this is always a mistery hehe

```
methods get_payroll
   importing it_rgdir        type hrpy_tt_rgdir
   returning value(rt_value) type ref to data.

method get_payroll.
   field-symbols: <lt_payroll> type standard table.
   create data rt_value type standard table of (mv_py_struct_type).
   assign rt_value->* to <lt_payroll>.
   ...
endmethod.
```

My intention was to have the returning value with another type, a known type, with which I can use the two known components more easily. The idea I had was to create a type with only the unknown field as ref to data, than have a table of it.

This way, I would be able to use it inside methods without having to work so "dynamicaly", which altough works perfectly, is kind of difficult to understand only by reading the code.

```
types begin of gty_s_generic_payroll.
   types evp   type pc261.
   types inter type pay99_international.
   types nat   type ref to data.
   types end of gty_s_generic_payroll.

types gty_t_generic_payroll type table of gty_s_generic_payroll.
```

The problem is, how to use an itab of type `gty_t_generic_payroll` as declared above?

I must somehow create the component 3, but I have no idea how to do it...

At the end, I have a generic field-symbol, that is type table, that has the two known components + the third one that was discovered during processing time.

So how can I pass the content of this field symbol to a table type `gty_t_generic_payroll`?

```
data lt_payroll            type ref to data.
field-symbols <lt_payroll> type any table.
lt_payroll = mo_payroll->get_payroll( lt_rgdir ). "this will return type ref to data
assign lt_payroll->* to <lt_payroll>.
```

After executing this code `<lt_payroll>` has all the values, but it is a dynamic table where I cannot use components `<lt_payroll>[1]-inter`.

So how to pass   to `gty_t_generic_payroll`-typed variable, so that I can access components without much dynamics?

Comment: Why do you define your field-symbol `<lt_payroll>` of type `any table` instead of with type `gty_t_generic_payroll`? If the only dynamics of your field is in the third component of the row structure, you can access to the components as you intended, with `<lt_payroll>[1]-inter` and so on. You can even access component `nat`, but it is of type `ref to data` of course. You'll have to derefence and assign it in order to access it.

Comment: You say "how do I use an itab of type gty_t_generic_payroll" but I don't understand where is your difficulty. Can you show a code snippet to illustrate how you'd like to use it?

Comment: Hello, rplantiko, I must use that field symbol as any table because the values I take come from a standard function module that only accepts internal tables as exporting parameters. This way, ```<lt_payroll>``` is considered a internal table and the function module works

Comment: hello, Sandra... indeed my coments were a little confusing, but nevertheless, I was able to populate a table type gty_t_generic_payroll with the data from <lt_payroll>. I updated the post with how I did it. Unfotunately, I lost performance,  but I guess it can't be helped. The code gets either a little slower but much easier to understand, or faster and you need more attention to get what's going on.

Comment: Using some intermediate variable is worth sometimes, if it uses little memory, but here I guess it's not the case, so I wouldn't create an intermediate variable, and you don't explain why it would be so complex to use the original variable directly.

Comment: This is not a question - it is a book! :-D

Comment: Hello, Sandra, the problem with using the whole table as dynamic is that it must be used in a lot of other methods as dynamic. This means I must create a bunch of field symbols assigning components from the table, cannot loop using  where, even read table must be done dynamicaly, which at the end makes the code less readable, altough fully working. Now, with this new table not-so-dynamic, whomever tries to read the code, will understand it at first glance, to support, who debug all day, it is extremely helpful :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was able to pass the values from the fully generic table (type ref to data) to another table that is 1/3 generic (type gty_t_generic_payroll):

```
  methods get_payroll
    importing it_rgdir        type hrpy_tt_rgdir
    returning value(rt_value) type gty_t_generic_payroll.

  method get_payroll.

    data lt_payroll     type gty_t_generic_payroll.
    data lt_payroll_aux type ref to data.

    field-symbols: <lt_payroll_aux> type standard table.

    create data lt_payroll_aux type standard table of (mv_py_struct_type).

    assign lt_payroll_aux->* to <lt_payroll_aux> .

    call function ' '.

    call function ' '
      exporting
             = mv_relid
             = mv_pernr
             = xsdbool( gs_parm-use_natio <> abap_true )
      tables
             = it_rgdir
             = <lt_payroll_aux> "table with the values I need
      exceptions
             = 0.

    if sy-subrc <> 0.
      return.
    endif.

    loop at <lt_payroll_aux> assigning field-symbol(<ls_payroll_aux>).

      assign component 1 of structure <ls_payroll_aux> to field-symbol(<evp>).
      assign component 2 of structure <ls_payroll_aux> to field-symbol(<inter>).
      assign component 3 of structure <ls_payroll_aux> to field-symbol(<nat>).

      data(ls_value) = value gty_s_generic_payroll(
        evp   = <evp>
        inter = <inter>
      ).

      get reference of <nat> into ls_value-nat.

      append ls_value to rt_value. "returning table, with values I need and 
                                   "now with 2/3 known types

    endloop.

  endmethod.
```

At the end of the day, I acomplished what I needed, but unfortunately I do loose a lot of performance, since I must loop twice in the results now.

- to populate the not-so-dynamic-table
- to do the actual process of the report (at least it gets pretier lol)

This is the only way because I can't simply use `insert lines of dynamic_itab to not_so_dynamic_itab`, since the third component is reference .

Comment: The rule of thumb here: if you want readability in `in a lot of other methods` you cannot omit wrapping original table into new type. If you want performance, just use  original table dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Given your target structure and table like this:

```
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF payroll_row_type,
    known_first_component  TYPE something_we_know,
    known_second_component TYPE something_else_we_know,
    discovered_component   TYPE REF TO data,
  END OF payroll_row_type.

TYPES payroll_table_type TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF payroll_row WITH EMPTY KEY.
```

If you now have another table, whose type at runtime is:

```
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF discovered_row_type,
    known_first_component  TYPE something_we_know,
    known_second_component TYPE something_else_we_know,
    known_third_component  TYPE some_data_type,
  END OF discovered_row_type.

TYPES discovered_table_type TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF discovered_row WITH EMPTY KEY.
```

You can move one to the other with

```
DATA source TYPE discovered_table_type.
DATA target TYPE payroll_table_type.
DATA resolved_component TYPE REF TO DATA.

DATA(descriptor) = 
  cl_abap_elemdescr=>describe_by_data( source_row-known_third_component ).

LOOP AT source INTO DATA(source_row).

  DATA(target_row) =
    VALUE payroll_row_type(
      known_first_component  = source_row-known_first_component
      known_second_component = source_row-known_second_component ).

  CREATE DATA target_row-discovered_component TYPE descriptor.
  ASSIGN source_row-known_third_component TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<source_component>).
  ASSIGN target_row-discovered_component TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<target_component>).
  <target_component> = <source_component>.

  INSERT target_row INTO TABLE target.

ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Hello, Florian, yes, that is how I ended up doing, but for the last component, the unknown one, I did slightly different:

```abap
get reference of <nat> into ls_value-nat.
append ls_value to rt_value. 
```

this way, I work wit the return table using this unknown component as a reference (->*), and the other two I can work with normaly, since they aren't dynamic, You can check it in the last part of the question, I recently edited it adding this solution!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The question and answers may look confusing for future visitors (what is the actual question?), so here is my two cents.

Summary of the question :

- You call an external code (1) which gives you an internal table generated dynamically, but you know that all the components are always the same except one which varies but is at the same position, so you'd like to refer to its components statically, except for the one which varies.

  (1) so, you can't adapt it.
- Your workaround is to define an equivalent internal table statically and the component which varies will be defined as a data reference type (pointer to any data object), then to initialize it by copying the data from the dynamic internal table.
- You ask for another better solution because yours consumes extra memory (two internal tables) and decreases the performance (copy process).

Answer :

- No better solution